# C - XOR Loop - Kattis - Oddmanout

Tags: c, loops, xor

I'm new to programming. I am learning XOR to attempt the oddmanout question on Kattis for a classroom homework problem.

What I am attempting is to find the odd man in a series of numbers. Every number save one has a pair. I have to find the number that doesn't. My code below is supposed to XOR each number in an array to find that "odd man".

However, as I don't know why XOR is outputting the incorrect answer, I am posting on this site, asking for help.

My input is :

```
3
3
1 2147483647 2147483647
5 
3 4 7 4 3
5
2 10 2 10 5
```

My output is:

```
Case #1: 3
Case #2: 4
Case #3: 4
```

I expected to get:

```
Case #1: 1
Case #2: 7
Case #3: 5
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int N,i,n,j,a=0,num=1;
  int guest[1000],cas[16];
  scanf("%d",&N);

  printf("N is: %d\n",N);

  while(N!=0){
    scanf("%d",&n);
    j=0;

printf("n is: %d\n",n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      scanf("%d",&guest[i]);
      j=j^i;

      printf("guests are: %d\n",guest[i]);
    }

printf("j is: %d\n",j);

    cas[a]=j;
    a++;
    N--;

    printf("N is: %d\n a is: %d\n",N,a);

  }


  for(i=0;i<a;i++){
    printf("Case #%d: %d\n",num,cas[i]);
    num++;
  }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: A recommendation: get into the habit of commenting your code, and naming your variables as something related to their purpose. It makes it easier to catch mistakes and makes it *much* easier for other people to read your code.

Comment: @user3528438: thank you so much! I could not find that for the life of me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user3528438 mentioned in a comment, your line `j=j^i;` should be `j=j^guest[i];`. You want to XOR with members of the array you have entered, not with the index of the array.

You should get into the habit of commenting your code early, and naming your variables something that makes your code easier to read. It makes it much easier to catch mistakes like this, and will save you heartache if you have to go back to your code later.